# Ideal Low Pass Filter shifted is still ideal Low Pass Filter?

Tags: filter, low-pass

[image]maybe a stupid question.
But let us say we have a ideal LPF filter like this:
$$H\left(j\omega \right)=\begin{cases}1&-\omega _m<\omega <\omega _m\\ 0&else\end{cases}$$
If I shift it , which means like that:
$$H\left(j\omega \right)=\begin{cases}1&\omega _m<\omega <3\omega _m\\ 0&else\end{cases}$$
Is it still ideal LPF filter?
Because we know the "shape" of LPF fitler is like a step function of
$$u(t+1)-u(t-1)$$

I know my question is a little stupid, but it is important to me.

EDIT:
I was said in comments it will be Band Pass Filter, but how? band pass filter looks like double shifted LPF, not one.
[image]

EDIT:

Comment: The shifted LPF will be a band pass filter.

Comment: but band pass filter has two squares, I mean, two places like LPF
How is it possible?

Comment: @StefanWyss Hi, edited in post the BPF, that is not logical to me how it will be BPF, please explain to me

Comment: Forget about negative frequencies. They have no relevance other than math.

Comment: So basically the difference between LPF and BPF is actually the shift? and so is with HPF with BSF

Comment: This filter **passes** a ***band*** from 100 - 200 Hz.

Comment: Oh it wasnt my question, but thanks :)
And he already answered me, for some reason it got deleted, but I got my answer
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The filter response cannot be shifted this way.

The negative values of angular velocity are a mirror image of the positive values.

The definition for a low pass filter is based on the positive values of \$\omega\$. The 0 Hz boundary cannot be shifted.

When a corner frequency of a filter is shifted to the right, the image corner frequency is shifted to the left, and vice versa.

Perhaps frequency should be calculated as \$f=\left|\frac{\omega}{2\pi}\right|\$.

Comment: Hmm, if I am understanding correct.
When you said that if I shift it, it cannot be shifted.
So when I shift it, I basically make it BPF ( as before it was LPF ). Am I right?

Comment: You can draw whatever you like. In a real filter, there is only one corner frequency. The negative sign indicates 180 degree phase shift.